# Coffeescript timer and 'this' pointer on callback

Tags: coffeescript

I'm having a problem with what the browser considers 'this' to be. In the following example, calling pingMe() on abc will wait 1 second and then the browser will say that Object DOMWindow has no method 'func'. Instead of resolving 'this' to the instance of class ABC (abc), it instead resolves to the DOMWindow, as if the object wasn't involved. I'm clearly not understanding how setTimeout works with respect to callback scope. Any suggestions how i can make this callback succeed?

```
class ABC
  @func = null

  constructor: (func) ->
    @func = func

  pingMe: ->
    setTimeout(doPing, 1000)

  doPing = ->
    @func()

abc = new ABC ->
  alert "HI"
abc.pingMe()
```

Comment: hm, changing the setTimeout line to `obj = this; setTimeout((-> obj.doPing()), 1000)` and the doPing declaration to `doPing: ->` seems to fix it. It looks like CoffeeScript keeps regular JavaScript behavior in these scenarios.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got this code working.

```
class ABC
  @func = null

  constructor: (func) ->
    @func = func

  pingMe: ->
    setTimeout =>
     @doPing()
    , 1000

  doPing: ->
    @func()

abc = new ABC ->
  alert "HI"
abc.pingMe()
```

Your doPing method was defined `doPing = ->`, whereas the others all use `name: ->`, I changed it that way. `pingMe` uses `=>` to create a unnamed function, and `@doPing` to bind `this` to the function.

Not sure if this is correct, I rarely use JavaScript. But I hope it might give you a direction to look further.

Comment: yep that's it. my knowledge of `=>` was lacking.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution which is closer to what you would do in ES5 is:

```
pingMe: ->
    setTimeout(@doPing.bind(@), 1000)
```

or if you want to save on parentheses:

```
pingMe: ->
    setTimeout (@doPing.bind @), 1000
```

*Note that `bind` is ES5, so only [available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Browser_compatibility) in IE from version 9.*

---

Also note, you should at all costs ***avoid*** the temptation to try:

```
    setTimeout(@doPing.bind @, 1000)    # BAD!
       or
    setTimeout @doPing.bind @, 1000     # BAD!
```

because both of those pass the number as the second argument to `bind`, not `setTimeout`!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps for a little more clarity, you can bind the "doPing" method instead. It'll look a bit cleaner and FWIW, I think it better expresses what you're looking to achieve.

```
class ABC
  @func = null

  constructor: (func) ->
    @func = func

  pingMe: ->
    setTimeout => @doPing, 1000

  doPing: =>
    @func()

abc = new ABC ->
  alert "HI"
abc.pingMe()
```

Comment: I believe that should be `=> @doPing()`.  `=> @doPing` evaluates to a function which returns the bound function, not a function that calls the bound function.  See Reiner's answer.